# artifactory jenkins plugin with first class nuget support like maven packages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Looking here I have methods for maven but i cant find nuget:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins

How do I use the jenkins plugin to upload packages with Nuget Info attached to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you must use the jfrog cli or the upload() method of the plugin to add build info and do retention. You cannot upload with regular nuget methods.

Answer (score 2):

It sure looks like Nuget is not supported within the plugin ([plugin source on github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin)).   [Nuget CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) is probably the next stop and then you'll want to figure out how to update the buildInfo with the package so the two objects can be linked together for management and cleanup.  I don't know how to do that step yet but the REST interface.  Also, theres a [MSBUILD Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/MSBuild+Artifactory+Plugin) that might make this easier.

Publish would look something like this:

```
nuget push package -Source artifactoryRepoURL -ApiKey ArtifactoryAPIKey
```

On the Home artifactory page, there's a *Set Me Up* link for each repo that goes over the details.